# Update Sysdate - 10 min in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sysdate

I need to update a date column, with sysdate but 10 mins past. Is there any way to do?

Please help.

Comment: I tried this. but didn't work. update table 
set modified_date =  (sysdate - 10/(24*60))
where property_name = 'xxx';

Comment: Define "didn't work".  Did you get an error?  If so, what error?  Did it update the expected number of rows?  Why don't you believe it is correct?

Comment: I updated single row and committed after updating and tried select with to_char function.

Comment: Does the table have an update trigger that sets `modified_date` to `sysdate`? That will override the values used in the `update` statement.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance You are really great, you found the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: "[Triggers] cause a long-term maintenance headache. Triggers are tiny bits of code that are not run directly by anything—they just “happen” as a side effect of some other operation. Because their work is done as a side effect, people frequently forget that triggers are there. (And reviewing code for all side effects is difficult, if not impossible.)" -- Tom Kyte http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html. OTOH, an update trigger to set update date is one of the few places I will use a trigger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this probably

```
select sysdate - 10/(24*60) from dual;
```

Comment: I have tried it already, but didn't work. Thanks for the response.

Comment: What didn't work? show me the exact query you tried; probably will be able to help more.

Comment: this one. ` update table set modified_date = (sysdate - 10/(24*60)) where property_name = 'xxx';`

Comment: Check your `modified_date` column in table and validate whether it has really changed or not.

Comment: I checked the column data, It is getting updated to sysdate only.

Comment: @Vanathi: you are probably not displaying the time part correctly. Change your NLS settings to also see the hours, minutes and seconds

Comment: I'll repeat the question asked earlier by @ShannonSeverance: are there any UPDATE triggers on the table in question which might set MODIFIED_DATE for you?  To find such triggers on your table try `SELECT * FROM USER_TRIGGERS WHERE TRIGGERING_EVENT LIKE '%UPDATE%' AND TABLE_OWNER = 'YOUR_USER' AND TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE'`.  Then go through them and see if any trigger alters the column MODIFIED DATE.  Good luck.

Answer (score 8):

```
UPDATE the_table
   SET the_column = current_timestamp - interval '10' minute
WHERE pk = 42;
```

It certainly works, see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a1986/2

Comment: it didnt work. `update table 
set modified_date =  (current_timestamp - interval '20' minute)
where property_name = 'xxx';`

Comment: @Vanathi: *didn't work* is not a valid Oracle error message. And your statement makes it **20** minutes earlier even though you wanted **10** minutes

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found the issue.